# Setting NSLinkAttributeName font color

Tags: ios, nsmutableattributedstring

I feel like I'm missing something easy but I can't seem to find out how to do this:

I set the attribute to a link like so:

```
[myAttrString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:linkURL range:selectedRange];
```

That works but the link is blue and I can't seem to change the color. This sets everything except the link to white:

```
[myAttrString addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor whiteColor] range:selectedRange];
```

Is there another color attribute name that I can't seem to find that is specific to links?

Answer (score 65):

1. Use a `UITextView`
2. Set the `UITextView`'s `linkTextAttributes` like so:

   ```
   textView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor]};
   ```

Comment: This answer works but only if you can bind to a UITextView. Doesn't work for UILabel.

Comment: this question is about NSAttributedString, not UITextView

Comment: Well, if you can't do it with an NSAttributedString, then the next best thing is an answer that can achieve what you want.  And this answer is that.

Answer (score 4):

I actually ended up using [TTTAttributedLabel](https://github.com/twotoasters/TTTAttributedLabel/) for my label and then was able to do the following which worked perfectly:

```
NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor whiteColor],
                                 (id)kCTUnderlineStyleAttributeName: [NSNumber numberWithInt:kCTUnderlineStyleSingle]
                                 };
self.lblDescription.linkAttributes = linkAttributes;
```

Answer (score 4):

`txtLabel.linkAttributes = @{};`

This is the right one, call this line before set any other attribute

Comment: Wow I couldn't believe this would work... but it did. I really don't understand "why" though, but thanks.

Comment: This answer saved me a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

> **Explanation:**

This is surprisingly easy, text components that supports **link** detection have a property called `linkTextAttributes`.

This property stores the **style** for the link as of the component can apply it when detects a new link.

Summing up, your style will be applied and then the **style** stored in this property (in this order), successfully overriding your desired style.

> **Solution:**

Set this property to empty ( `linkTextAttributes = [:]` ) and take total control of you link Styles.

---

> **TIP: This can be used to create *touchable* elements on your `UITextView` that behaves like a button**. Creating a Really nice effect

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It works for multiple links with different styles.

Answer (score 2):

For swift (for reference for others):

```
// Color the links
var linkAttributes: NSMutableDictionary = NSMutableDictionary()
linkAttributes.setValue(self.appDelegate.variables.color320, forKey: NSForegroundColorAttributeName)

myTextView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes as [NSObject : AnyObject]
```

Answer (score 2):

For **Swift 3**

```
var aURL = "Http:// Your URL"
var description = "Click Me："
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: description + aURL)

/// Deal with link color
let foundURLRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: aURL)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: aURL, range: foundURLRange)
textview.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.yellow]

/// Deal with description color
let foundDescriptionRange = attributedString.mutableString.range(of: description)
attributedString.addAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.red, range: foundDescriptionRange)

textview.attributedText = attributedString
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
txtLabel.linkAttributes = @{};

NSMutableAttributedString * string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:expression];

{
[string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:result.range];

[string addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:@"link" range:result.range];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use TTTAttributedLabel, Oren's answer is worked.But you need to pay attention to the linkAttributes's warning in annotation.

> /**
>   A dictionary containing the default `NSAttributedString`
>   attributes to be applied to links detected or manually added to the
>   label text. The default link style is blue and underlined.
>
> @warning You must specify `linkAttributes` before setting autodecting or
>   manually-adding links for these attributes to be applied.
>   */
>
> @property (nonatomic, strong) NSDictionary *linkAttributes;