# Change the color of a link in an NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, iphone, nsattributedstring, nsmutableattributedstring

I have the following code but my links are always blue. How do I cange the color of them?

```
[_string addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName value:tag range:NSMakeRange(position, length)];
[_string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Bold" size:(12.0)] range:NSMakeRange(position, length)];
[_string addAttribute:NSStrokeColorAttributeName value:[UIColor greenColor] range:NSMakeRange(position, length)];
```

_string is a NSMutableAttributedString and the position and length work fine.

Comment: I used this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457131/setting-nslinkattributename-font-color

Answer (score 240, accepted):

## Swift

*Updated for Swift 4.2*

Use `linkTextAttributes` with a `UITextView`

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
```

And in context:

```
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "The site is www.google.com.")
let linkRange = (attributedString.string as NSString).range(of: "www.google.com")
attributedString.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.link, value: "https://www.google.com", range: linkRange)
let linkAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any] = [
    NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green,
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineColor: UIColor.lightGray,
    NSAttributedString.Key.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue
]

// textView is a UITextView
textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes
textView.attributedText = attributedString
```

## Objective-C

Use `linkTextAttributes` with a `UITextView`

```
textView.linkTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor greenColor]};
```

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25655606/3681880)

And from [this post](http://www.raywenderlich.com/48001/easily-overlooked-new-features-ios-7#textViewLinks):

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"This is an example by @marcelofabri_"];
[attributedString addAttribute:NSLinkAttributeName
                         value:@"username://marcelofabri_"
                         range:[[attributedString string] rangeOfString:@"@marcelofabri_"]];


NSDictionary *linkAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor],
                                 NSUnderlineColorAttributeName: [UIColor lightGrayColor],
                                 NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName: @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle)};

// assume that textView is a UITextView previously created (either by code or Interface Builder)
textView.linkTextAttributes = linkAttributes; // customizes the appearance of links
textView.attributedText = attributedString;
textView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I have been able to change link color, but how Can I change the color that appears when you keep pressing the link?

Comment: Perfect but in swift 4.4 Use `textView.linkTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor.rawValue: UIColor.green]`

Answer (score 53):

The link color is the tint color of the label/textView. So, you can change it by changing the tint color of the view. However, this will not work if you want different link colours within the same view.

Comment: Working for me on iOS 12.

Comment: Works nicely for UITextView

Comment: Does not work in Xcode 11.2.1, Swift 5 for UILabel @crcalin

Comment: @ios just use UITextView instead, it works with it

Answer (score 10):

*Swift*

```
 let str = "By using this app you agree to our Terms and Conditions and Privacy Policy"
 let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: str)
 var foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.rangeOfString("Terms and Conditions")

 attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: termsAndConditionsURL, range: foundRange)
 foundRange = attributedString.mutableString.rangeOfString("Privacy Policy")
 attributedString.addAttribute(NSLinkAttributeName, value: privacyURL, range: foundRange)
 policyAndTermsTextView.attributedText = attributedString
 policyAndTermsTextView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor()]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 NSAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"here" attributes:@{ @"myCustomTag" : @(YES), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Semibold" size:15], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) }];
```

Objective-C

This will make underlined white clickable text. Select necessary attributes for your code and use it.

To have string with clickable link in it do next:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Click " attributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Semibold" size:15]}];
NSAttributedString* attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"here" attributes:@{ @"myCustomTag" : @(YES), NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"SourceSansPro-Semibold" size:15], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle) }];
[string appendAttributedString:attributedString];
```

As a result you will get string 'Click here' and 'here' will be a link. You can set different styles to each string.

Answer (score 1):

For swift3.0

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

  let linkAttributes = [
        NSLinkAttributeName: NSURL(string: "http://stalwartitsolution.co.in/luminutri_flow/terms-condition")!
        ] as [String : Any]
  let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Please tick box to confirm you agree to our Terms & Conditions, Privacy Policy, Disclaimer. ")

  attributedString.setAttributes(linkAttributes, range: NSMakeRange(44, 18))

  attributedString.addAttribute(NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName, value: NSNumber(value: 1), range: NSMakeRange(44, 18))

  textview.delegate = self
  textview.attributedText = attributedString
  textview.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.red]
  textview.textColor = UIColor.white
  }


  func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldInteractWith URL: URL, in characterRange: NSRange, interaction: UITextItemInteraction) -> Bool {
    return true
   }
```

Comment: This line `textview.linkTextAttributes` worked with me when I set it after I set `attributedText`