# iOS UItextview link attribute colour not applying to attributed text

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have UITextview which is assigned to attributed text, It is rendering correctly but its not applying the link colour, in below snippet the  link colour is #EB0A1E but in textview it is visible as blue(default link color)

```
textView.attributedText = "Google.com link <a href = \"https://google.com\" style=color:#EB0A1E;>here</a><br><br> Hello there".htmlToAttributedString

extension String {

    var htmlToAttributedString: NSAttributedString? {
        guard let data = data(using: .utf8) else { return NSAttributedString() }
        do {
            return try NSAttributedString(data: data, options: [.documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html, .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue], documentAttributes: nil)
        } catch {
            return NSAttributedString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28361072/change-the-color-of-a-link-in-an-nsmutableattributedstring/32222702#32222702) answer from @Suragch? It is working for me. I just used different color.

[image: textView with image]

Comment: I cannot hard code the link colour as green in link attributes, It should take the colour from the html itself

Comment: I suppose you can't use webview for showing HTML?

Comment: @RamaKrish I don't think it is possible to do it by just rendering HTML in textview. Even this library [link](https://github.com/nicolasgoutaland/GONMarkupParser) cant do it: "Color style won't be applied to links. You have to use linkTextAttributes attribute from your UITextView to set it."

Comment: @RamaKrish maybe you can parse color from HTML and then use it as a variable for an answer I proposed?

Comment: we cannot use web view not sure how to parse the html and render