# NSAttributedString different link color

Tags: swift, uikit, nsattributedstring

Is it possible to have different .link colors in NSAttributedString?

for example i have

```
let style : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .link: "https://www.test.com",
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.red,
            NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
            NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor: UIColor.red
        ]
let style2 : [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
            .link: "https://www.anotherTest.com",
            NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.green,
            NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue,
            NSAttributedString.Key.strikethroughColor: UIColor.green
        ]
```

and applied in a range

I tried

```
view.linkTextAttributes = style
```

but there is no range option and it is applied to all .links

i also tried to overwrite foregroundColor

```
textStorage.addAttribute(NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor, value: UIColor.red, range: range)
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32222702/4490923

Comment: @Asteroid linkAttributes is added to all links present. Cannot be added to a range

Comment: You might need to override the methods in the CoreText part, or maybe with NSLayoutManager, on the drawing point https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nslayoutmanager