# iOS UITextView wrong link style

Tags: ios, uitextview

I have standart `UITextView`. When I set  in the `UITextView` text like

```
textView.text = "(614)594-2470\n(614)594-2231\nwww.rclexpressllc.com\n\n"
```

I get this on UI *(wrong link style)*
[image: wrong link style]

If I set  in the `UITextView` text like

```
textView.text = "tel: (614)594-2470 (call up to 20-00)\nfax: (614)594-2231 (accepts 24/7)\nsite: www.rclexpressllc.com (our awesome web-page)\n\n"
```

I get this on UI *(true link style)*
[image: true link style]

with what such behavior can be connected?
how to make `UITextView` work correctly?

Comment: Those links look fine for me. What is wrong with them?

Comment: do you see the difference between the second and the first screenshot?

Comment: add NSattributed string and assign it to textview 

NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Google" 
                                                                       attributes:@{ NSLinkAttributeName: [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"] }];
self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25457131/setting-nslinkattributename-font-color

Comment: NSAttributedString - the wrong way, I use auto detect links & phone in my UITextView

Comment: `textView.linkAttributes = [...]` not work for first point, only for second point, but second point and so good